# OSX's command line zip creates root directory

Tags: macos, command-line, zip

I'm trying to compress files, directly into a zip. What happens is that the zip automatically creates an initial directory in the zip with the name of the zip. Example:

```
zip -r0 myfile mydir/
```

Will create mydir inside the zip and then put the files inside.

Going into the directory doesn't help:

```
cd mydir
zip -r0 ../myfile *
```

Does the same.

How can I avoid that without using -j? I need the rest of the structure to stay, just not assume I need a directory inside that I don't.

Comment: Did you try `cd mydir` `zip -r0 ../myfile ./*`?

Comment: I did, still same thing.

Answer (score 1):

You should do `zip -r0 myfile.zip mydir`

Comment: No change, is there a flag I'm missing?

Comment: Which version of OS X are you using?

Comment: I'm using Mavericks

Answer (score 0):

On Mavericks

```
cd <folder>
zip -r ../<folder>.zip *
```

works for me